# Getting average CPU frequency

Tags: linux, grep, cpu-usage

Which command should I use to get the average CPU frequency? `inxi -C` requires `sudo`.

I looked on the internet, but could not find a non-sudo command that would display what I want. I don't mind grepping and stuff, but I want to get just that info to display it in a notification.

I also tried `lscpu`, but that doesn't display the current CPU frequency, just min and max.

Is there a way to average the results of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz` directly in one line?

My goal is to get a notification with all the important system information.

Comment: What average might you be referring to? The momentary average speed across all CPU cores/threads? Or some average over time?

Comment: Momentary across all CPU cores/threads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command can average the results of `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep MHz`
in one line:

```
grep MHz /proc/cpuinfo | awk '{print $4}' | awk '{temp+=$1;n++} END{printf("%f\n", temp/n);}'
```

Reference : [CPU Frequency Scaling](https://leo.leung.xyz/wiki/CPU_Frequency_Scaling).

Comment: An optimized version of your answer: `awk '/MHz/{ temp+=$4; n++ } END{ printf("%f\n", temp/n) }' /proc/cpuinfo`